# XPath selector for JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xpath

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin or anything that will allow me to easily select elements through xpath after parsing an XML using `$.parseXML`.
There's no way to use CSS selectors, as that's a javascript port for a .NET program that already uses XPath selectors.

I've seen a lot of questions asked on the matter, but couldn't see any viable answers, while it looks quite a basic need, and it came as a surprise when I learned it's not supported.

Thanks!

EDIT:
The problem is NOT parsing the XML, that I know how to do.
The problem is running XPath queries on the parsed XML.

Right now the required support is for Android and iOS native browsers(that are both webkit-based), but Windows Phone might need support soon too.

Comment: Do you need cross-browser support? I'm not sure about other browsers, but Mozilla does support XPath (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript))

Comment: As Todd points out, you don't need anything special to parse XML in jQuery -- just use the same tag and attribute selectors you would use on an HTML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found no good answer.

As a viable alternative I've found this nice library from GoogleCode: http://goog-ajaxslt.sourceforge.net/ 
There's a cross-browser XPath implementation there that can be used independently from the whole framework, and work's great.

Answer (score 0):

You can get xml values like this:

```
$(myXML).find('person').each(function(i, val) {
  // i is the counter of this element
  var age = $(val).attr('age'); // this is an attribute of the person node
  var firstName = $(val).find('firstname').text();
  var lastName = $(val).find('lastname').text();
}
```

This will work with:

```
...
<person age="3">
<firstname>Babe</firstname>
<lastname>Ruth</lastname>
</person>
<person age="44">
<firstname>Hank</firstname>
<lastname>AAron</lastname>
</person>
...
```

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
$('person', myXML).each(function(){
    //blah
});
```

The selector takes two parameters. The second parameter is the context in which to find the selector which defaults to `document`